# pypugjs syntax for returned render_template

Tags: python, flask

Is there a better syntax for the returned rendered view template.
The way i do it now is by using **{% include template_body %}**, which works but is rather ugly.

Example template:

```
doctype html
html(lang="eng")
head
    include head.pug


body
    div.ui.secondary.pointing.menu
        a(href='/').brand.item= brand
        // menu
        include flaskmenu.pug
        include userstatus.pug
        // menu
    div
        // flash message
        include flashmessage.pug
        // flash message

    div
        // body
        {% include template_body %}
        // body
```

The template_body is generated by the follow flask view:

```
@blueprint_home.route('/')
def index():
user = g.user

return render_template('index.pug',
                       user=user,
                       template_body='home.pug',
                       flaskmenu=template_show_menu(),
                       )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a block tag instead so your index.pug will feature a

```
block content
```

And *home.pug* will look like this:

```
extends.index.pug

block content
  .main here goes the content
```

Comment: read more about it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-block